# Other than Visual Studio, which designers can we use to create windows workflow activities?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Can we use any other designers (possible web based) that can be used to create windows workflow activities?

Comment: You can embed the WF designer because it's a WPF control but you won't be able to throw that into a web application, sorry.

Comment: We don't have a web designer (yet) but we know that it is a high priority for our customers. What we really need to know is more information about your scenario. Imagine you did have a web designer.
Can you tell me a story about how your designer would be used?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the .Net Framework has facility to re-host the WF designer. It is relatively easy and you will find loads of examples online. However, it is NOT web-based.

There are some Web based designers, like [this one](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wfxbap/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4668), but I do not know of their reliability.

My suggesting would be to stick for the WPF version. And perhaps use something like click once to make it easy to install and update.